# How to generate a context-free grammar that defines a regex expression

Tags: context-free, regular-expressions

As the title says, I have been asked to generate a grammar that defines the language of regular expressions. The symbols are: + . * | ? char

I tried and came up with this but it doesn't work when trying to create a parse tree so it's wrong but I'm so lost on how to even begin to define the different rules. So any help either on the question specifically, on improving/re-writing what I got, or general step-by-step guidance to figuring out how to write a grammar from just being given symbols is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Comment: Start with a (recursive) definition of the regular expressions.